# Calling pthread_join on a pthread_t which may not have been created

Tags: pthreads, posix, pthread-join

We have a class that has a protected pthread_t variable. Once that class has been constucted, the pthread_t exists, but it hasn't had an ID assigned to it which is what pthread_create does.

Is it OK to call pthread_join on the pthread_t variable in this case?

If I understand the man page for pthread_join correctly it should return a ESRCH error but this man page can be interpreted differently.

Comment: How do you know your `pthread_t` variable doesn't contain the ID of a thread that has been created, thus causing the caller to wait for the wrong thread?

Comment: Good point. Somehow I assumed the pthread_t would be created and the ID initialised to an ID that was 0 / not possible. Is it possible to look at pthread_t and check if the ID has been set?

Comment: *Is it possible to look at pthread_t and check if the ID has been set?*  You can use a debugger or emit a log message of some type with the value of the ID.  How do you initialize the value?

Comment: I don't know how it is initialised. Pthread_create sets that ID according to the man page. I am just trying to avoid carrying an 'initialised' flag around. If I can call pthread_join on a pthread_t that has not been used in conjunction with pthread_create then thats great. If I can somehow look at a pthread_t object and check myself if it has been 'created' then that is fine too.

Comment: Your `pthread_t` value has to start with some value - it's either indeterminate or initialized to a specific value.

Answer (score 1):

pthread_t is nothing but unsigned long int, thus during declaration initialize it with 0 value. Now just before pthread_join just check if it is non zero.If it is zero then pthread_create is not called.